# In Orchard CMS, how can I get all items of a particular content type based in the values of an attached part's properties

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using Orchard 1.7.2.

I have created a new content type called `PropertyImage` of stereotype Media. I also created a part called `PropertyPart` and attached that part to my `PropertyImage` content type. This allows a user to pick a product when uploading a `PropertyImage` (ie to say 'This image is of this property').

So far so good.

Now what I'd like to do is query for all `PropertyImage`s that have a `PropertyPart` attached to them where the associated property is `x`, `y`, or `z`.

This is what I have so far:

```
var images = _orchardServices.ContentManager
    .Query<PropertyPart, PropertyRecord>()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyId == id)
    .ForType(new[] { "PropertyImage" });
```

This however will only return a collection of `PropertyPart`s, which is not what I want, because I want the whole `PropertyImage` Content Item. How can I do this?

I should point out that properties come from an external source, and are therefore not content items.

**Edit**

As soon as I asked this question, I realised I could just append my query with this:

```
.List().Select(p=>p.ContentItem)
```

Sometimes it just helps to talk your problem through!

Comment: Please mark your question as answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I asked this question, I realised I could just append my query with this:

```
.List().Select(p=>p.ContentItem)
```

Sometimes it just helps to talk your problem through!